# Undefined variable with symfony (admin-generator)

Tags: templates, symfony1, admin-generator

I wanted to create my own template for the admin-generator,
so I've followed a tutorial and i'm now making my own template based on the "admin" template.
But I defined a new variable called "rubrique" in the file "newAction" and when I tried to call it in the template "newSuccess.php" I obtained this error:

**Notice: Undefined variable: rubrique in C:\wamp\www\PhpProject2\data\generator\sfDoctrineModule\immo\template\templates\newSuccess.php on line**

- **newAction:**

  public function executeNew(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
  $this->rubrique =12;

  }
- **NewSuccess.php:**

  echo $rubrique;

ps: i've simplified the code

Does anybody have a solution?? sorry for my bad english :p

Comment: Is your template file called `NewSuccess.php` or `newSuccess.php`. I think the template filenames are case sensitive. Otherwise, it looks like it should work. How are you telling symfony to use your custom Admin Generator, in `generator.yml`?

Comment: the template is called 'newSuccess.php'

Comment: generator.yml:
'generator:
  class: sfDoctrineGenerator
  param:
    model_class:           Rubrique
    theme:                 immo
    non_verbose_templates: true
    with_show:             false
    singular:              ~
    plural:                ~
    route_prefix:          rubrique
    with_doctrine_route:   true
    actions_base_class:    sfActions'

Comment: What version of symfony are you using? Did you clear your cache? `./symfony cc`

Comment: I am using symfony 1.4 , and i cleared the cache without any result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the delay.

Okay... I think I might know your problem. I spent a chunk of time modifying the Admin Generator for a project, but that was over 1.5 years ago so I had to refresh my memory.

I'm taking an educated guess by saying you're echoing your variable in `data\generator\sfDoctrineModule\immo\template\templates\newSuccess.php` like so:

```
<?php echo $rubrique; ?>
```

These files are actually compiled first and then executed. In the first pass the var `$rubrique` is not available. Try this instead:

```
[?php echo $rubrique; ?]
```

Note the square brackets. I think the files are run through a regex or str_replace or something; I can't recall exactly.

Try this, then clear the cache `./symfony cc` which is important. It should work now.

Alternatively, override the template and put it in your module's dir and use it with normal php tags.

Hope this helps :)

**Edit:**

You might know this already, but if you want to override the file as described above it will be available in the cache: `cache\frontend\dev\modules\{$MODULE_NAME}\templates\newAction.php`, where `{$MODULE_NAME}` will be the name of your module prepended by the word `auto`; e.g: `autoUser`.

This overrides the cached version. Copy this into your module's template dir and edit to your heart's content.

Comment: Thank you Darragh, Your answer was really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

are you getting the error here?

**C:\wamp\www\PhpProject2\data\generator\sfDoctrineModule\immo\template\templates\newSuccess.php on line**

I'm not familiar with Doctrine but you should define your custom actions and templates inside

**apps/backend/modules/YOURMODULE/actions (for actions**)

and

**apps/backend/modules/YOURMODULE/templates (for templates)**

Did you follow the steps described [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/es/12)?
http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/es/12

Regards